# Environment variables not being accessed in Python script on VSCode

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-dotenv

I am creating a simple app that connects to an API and stores specific data into a list. In order to connect to the API, I must do BasicAuth with an email and password. Whenever I hardcode my email and password into the Python script, it works perfectly, however whenever I store these values in a `.env` file and do `os.getenv('EMAIL')`, I am getting a 401 error. I proceeded to print out the value of EMAIL and PASSWORD when `EMAIL = os.getenv('EMAIL')` and `PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')` but it is printing None in the console. Here is my code in the Python script:

```
    load_dotenv()
    EMAIL = os.getenv('EMAIL')
    PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
```

Here is what my .env file looks like:

```
    EMAIL = importantemail@mydomain.com  
    PASSWORD = secret_password
```

The two files are in the same folder but I am thinking that I need to do something like pointing my working directory to the folder that has the script and the .env file. This is my first full-fledged project so I believe that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: If it is printing None, that means that the variables could not be found by the function `getenv`. You need to make sure that the variables you have stored in the .env file are `exported as environment variables`.

Comment: Exporting the path of the .env file?

Comment: from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv()). Can you try this in your code?

Comment: I tried load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) but still got a 401 error.

Answer (score 1):

`os.getenv()` is for system environment variables like `HOME`, `PATH`, etc. This function does not read any data from your `.env` file.

You can use this [parser](http://to%20solve%20your%20problem), or parse file by your own with `os` package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case, would it be better if I created system environment variables with the values that I need?

Comment: I think no, system environment variables are used for more general purposes (also, they could be used by different applications/users). Whereas you wanna store application-related information. I would definitely use the env file and parse it.