# .env file not reading variables in

Tags: python, environment-variables

I read up on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70137247/environment-variables-not-being-accessed-in-python-script-on-vscode) but there's no code published as the solution. I created credentials.env with username and password, run it in VSCode but it only prints out my username, which I now realize is prints out my work userID regardless of what I put in the .env file. What does "exported as environment variables" mean and how does one do so?

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

username = os.getenv("username")
password = os.getenv("password")

print("username: ", username)
print("password: ", password)
```

and it prints out:

username:  (my work userID)

password: None

Answer (score 1):

The file has to literally be named `.env`.  It doesn't look for that extension.  `credentials.env` won't do it.

Comment: Should also probably be noted that the variable `USERNAME` would already be occupied  in PS/Bash so unless `override=True` is used it still wouldn't change.

Comment: alternatively, you can pass the file's path as a string to load_dotenv

Answer (score 0):

```
load_dotenv('C:/Users/MyWorkUserID/.env')
```

is all that was needed